# API Development in Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am building REST apis with Python using Flask. I am using jupiter notebook to run the following code snippet:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask import render_template
import pandas as pd
import ast

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Users(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data = pd.read_csv('users.csv')  # read local CSV
        data = data.to_dict()  # convert dataframe to dict
        return {'data': data}, 200  # return data and 200 OK

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return render_template('error.html'), 404

class Locations(Resource):
    pass
api.add_resource(Users, '/users/')  # add endpoints
api.add_resource(Locations, '/locations/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()  # run our Flask app
```

I am getting following error:

```
Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
Debug mode: off
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-10-27 23:01:38,207] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1945, in match
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 117, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: error.html
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2020 23:01:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I just want to test rest api. As shown in the above error, do I need to create template for that? How to do that in jupiter notebook?

Comment: What request causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` API endpoint which is not defined. Try accessing `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/` and it should work.

Second, to define templates, you need to create `error.html` inside a directory named `templates` in the same directory as of `app.py`